# How do I log-out (or reset) Microsoft's RMS / AIP [Azure Information Protection] identity on Windows for Word, Excel, Powerpoint, Outlook, AIP-Client?

Tags: microsoft-office, encryption, document-management

Microsoft 365 offers a RMS / Right Management Service called Azure Information Protection which is integrated with Outlook, Word, Excel. It encrypts documents of certain files, in a nutshell.

On a Windows computer switching between two office accounts *within* Word is relatively easy,  but switching the under-the-hood RMS/AIP account is harder. The experience seems to have changed over over time.

I wanted to provide a quick overview for those who went looking, I had some trouble finding the correct answer.

Leading source of information: [docs.Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/clientv2-admin-guide-customizations#sign-in-as-a-different-user).

**How do log-out or reset the AIP-user on a Windows PC?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: Read this as an experience in time. If SuperUser had supported it, I would have marked this answer for automatic review (expiration) every 6 months.

### Steps

The following worked for me at August 2021.

0. Check factors/preconditions below if needed like **Closing office apps**.
1. Right-click on a file and pretend you want to **[Classify and Encrypt]** it to get the AIP client.
2. Click on **[Help & Feedback]**.
3. Click on something that reads  ~**'Reset settings'** in your language and accept.
   (This action wilt at least remove the TokenCache file for you.)
4. Open the old Internet Explorer (and sigh) and press CTRL SHIFT DELETE and **delete all cookies**.
5. Now you can open your AIP-client (or Office application) and it should prompt you to log in and it should not go away automatically.

### Notes

I did not have to go into the registry, that strategy seem to have expired. This one might also expire over time. Feel free to leave your experience in the comments.

I had the problem of the AIP client automatically signed in again without SSO set-up (local account), so clearing the cookies in Internet Explorer helped me.

My scenario was for switching accounts from *different tenants; I do not recommend it* and I try to prevent switching as much as possible. (Switching of Office accounts works fine; just not the AIP-user.)

If you have two tenants, there is a chance one of your accounts is also a guest user in the other tenant. Be VERY aware of the MFA prompts. Once I noticed it tried to authenticate at the wrong tenant as a guest, in stead of the dedicated user. Unsure why.

I updated the AIP-client.

### Factors:

- SSO: If you have added your Microsoft 365 account to Windows completely (so not "just this app"), you might be automatically signed in. You can disconnect that connection in settings or add another account which triggers a choice. Be aware that Edge will also offer you that choice: *Every Single Time Everywhere.*
- Office applications; Close them before doing this.

---

Mac user? Read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395879/how-do-i-log-out-or-reset-microsofts-rms-aip-azure-information-protection).

---

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/clientv2-admin-guide-customizations#sign-in-as-a-different-user